# Change primary key type

Tags: php, eloquent

My primary key in my model is an uniqid() (13 characters with letters). When I do `$user->id` it only shows me the first number and forget the other chars.

```
App\Models\User::__set_state(array(
   'connection' => NULL,
   'table' => NULL,
   'primaryKey' => 'id',
   'keyType' => 'int',
   'incrementing' => true,
   'with' => 
  array (
  ),
   'perPage' => 15,
   'exists' => true,
   'wasRecentlyCreated' => false,
   'attributes' => 
  array (
    'id' => '58acab3993c2e',
    'email' => 'admin@admin.fr',
    'password' => '$2y$10$nR.2EnKMX/wCnIbN8Wt36.qF0nPnxcxXM/rIG2SxC0vCX8EtwGQg.',
    'fname' => 'Foo',
    'lname' => 'Bar',
    'role' => 0,
    'website' => '',
    'description' => '',
    'phone' => '',
    'picture' => 'static/uploads/58acab3993c2e.jpg',
    'admin' => 1,
    'accepted' => 1,
  ),
```

I think it's because my keyType is an int... How do I change this ? I use eloquent with slim.

Comment: How does `incrementing => true,` and `uniqid()` work together here?

Comment: But in phpmyadmin auto-increment is not on true :/